# How to disable struts 2 Table generation for Form?

Tags: java, struts2

Struts 2 automatically generate HTML table for it's `<s:form>` tag. How can I disable it? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: We need to start marking duplicates of this... This has been answered many times.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Struts2 have theme generation functionality based on which it generares either Table based HTMl code for its tags default is x_html which is your case .
You can avoid this by setting theme as simple on page level or each tags has theme property which will generate div based html contents

```
<s:form name="test" theme="simple">
```

or you can set theme for entire page as below
static value

```
<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />
```

property

```
<s:set name="theme" value="%{myTheme}" scope="page" />
```

you can set it across entire application by

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

Comment: If you'd like to accomplish this across your entire project then use <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" /> in your struts.xml file.

Answer (score 8):

Just add

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
```

**constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"** in struts.xml. It wont apply struts default themes.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be using the usual HTML  tag.

Comment: Very obvious and often overlooked!

Answer (score 1):

setting simple theme avoids the use of advanced validation in forms (i think). you should use css_xhtml template either adding following line to your struts.xml

`<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="css_xhtml" />`

or specifically in concrete areas of your code, like form

`<s:form name="test" theme="simple">`

This way you get html elements with their css classes assigned, ready to be styled with css.

Comment: i meant `<s:form name="test" theme="css_xhtml">`

Comment: simple theme is what you have mentioned css_xhtml

Comment: simple and css_xhtml are not the same. To avoid autogenerating opening and closing <table> tags inside de <s:form>, you should use css_xhtml: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/cssxhtml-theme.html